# "As good a deal as you'll ever get"

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis, indefinite-articles, big-mess-construction

I've identified a part of English speech where I always become stuck. Some examples will illustrate:

> "He's as great a man as you will ever find." // Fine
>
> "It's as good an option as you could hope for." // Fine
>
> "It's as wise a decision you could've made in the circumstances." //
>   Fine

I've looked this up and the words "man", "option" and "decision" are said to be the postcedents, and the first word of each sentence (which is a personal pronoun), are said to be cataphors. Confer anaphora and antecedent for opposites.

Now the problem arises (as I see it) if you try to use this same construction or pattern with the postcedent in each example in the plural form.

> "They're as great [a] men as you will ever find."
>
> "They're as good [an] options as you could hope for."
>
> "They're as wise [a] decisions you could've made in the
>   circumstances."

Whenever I find myself verbally walking down one of these paths, I get to the first indefinite article, and have to stop, all confused, and have to tread back to the start to reconstruct the sentence a different way.

Also, this doesn't just happen when using a pronoun. For example:

> "The Chief Justice is as moral a man as you will find."
>
> "The Supreme Court justices are as moral [a] men as you will find."

After thinking about it, I found that you can "cheat", so to speak, by forcing the thing referred to into a singular form. For example:

> "They're as great a group of men as you will ever find."
>
> "They're as good a set of options as you could hope for."
>
> "They're as wise a group of decisions you could have made in the
>   circumstances."

I know that this (as far as I know is acceptable), but what I'm really asking is whether you can complete the sentence without using this (hack or kludge), as I see it. In other words can you say:

> "They're as great men as you will ever find."

I don't think you can. This has always bugged me.

Comment: The plural forms as presented don't sound as good to me either. Turning the phrases around works better: e.g. *the options are as good as you could hope for*.

Comment: Sorry, Zebrafish… this is the first time in 50 years that I've understood the old joke: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this. Really? Then don't do that…"

No problem arises except as you imagined it. To the extent that using that construction or pattern with the postcedent in any example causes a problem, don't do that.

Simple semantics should stop any question of "They're as great men as you will ever find" because “they” can’t all be the one greatest.

How could anything else matter?

Comment: I don't like "It's as wise a decision you could've made in the circumstances", although *as* can sometimes be omitted in other contexts. Should it be "It's as wise a decision **as** you could've made in the circumstances"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sentences contain what is called the "Big Mess" construction*. It doesn't work with plural nouns because it requires the indefinite article:

> In English noun phrases the determiner canonically precedes the prenominal adjectives, both the lexical and the phrasal ones.
>
> (1) a. a big house
>
> b. a very big house
>
> (2) a. * big a house
>
> b. * very big a house
>
> A notable exception are the adjectival phrases which are introduced by ***as**, so, too, how, this* and *that*. When they occur in a nominal which contains the indefinite article, they precede the determiner (Huddleston and Pullum, 2002, 435).
>
> (3) a. It’s so good a bargain I can’t resist buying it.
>
> b. How serious a problem is it?
>
> (4) a. * It’s a so good bargain I can’t resist buying it.
>
> b. * A how serious problem is it?
>
> This construction, for which Berman (1974) coined the term Big Mess Construction, only occurs in nominals with an indefinite article. **It does not occur** in nominals
> with another kind of determiner, as in (5a), nor **in nominals without determiner**, as in (5b).

("[The Big Mess Construction](https://web.archive.org/web/20220322120804/https://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/HPSG/2007/vaneynde.pdf)", Frank Van Eynde, 2007. In Müller, Stefan (Ed.), *Proceedings of the 14th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar, Stanford Department of Linguistics and CSLI’s LinGO Lab,* 415–433. Page 416. **Bolding** added.)

So another way to rephrase is to move the adjective:

- "They're men as great as you will ever find."
- "They're options as good as you could hope for."
- "They're decisions as wise as you could've made in the circumstances."
  (I'm guessing you left out a second *as*? It doesn't sound grammatical to me without one.)

However, although I would say that these sentences are grammatical, they don't sound very natural to me. I think I would actually rephrase by making the plural noun the subject, like this:

- "These men are as great as you will ever find." (still sounds a bit awkward)
- "These options are as good as you could hope for."
- "Your decisions were as wise as they could have been in the circumstances."

---

*Some other questions about this construction:

- [If I can say "not that good a review," does that mean I can say "not that good reviews"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343861/if-i-can-say-not-that-good-a-review-does-that-mean-i-can-say-not-that-good-r)
- ["more of a"or "too much of a" in a plural sense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443932/more-of-aor-too-much-of-a-in-a-plural-sense?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- ["You're too clever a man"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92079/youre-too-clever-a-man/362455#362455)

Answer (score 1):

The construction  isn't all that "messy" *pace* Van Eynde et al.

It is saying that something, **an instance of class X**, is not likely to be less [adjective] than any other instance of class X, under the said circumstances. In making a comparative predication about **an example** of a class relative to the rest of the class, it is simply not amenable to a *plural* comparand. If you need to use a plural, that is, if you need to compare several things to the rest of the class, you must supply *a singular collective noun that groups them* (as you suggest), but that isn't always easy to do. And that's not a limitation of the language, as you would need to have a basis for comparing them *as a subset* against the other members of the class, and that basis doesn't always map neatly to a collective noun; and you may also have to make adjustments to the clause that describes the circumstances.

> It is as good **a car** as you can hope to find in your price range.
>
> These are as good **a couple of cars** as you can hope to find in your price range.

> He is as fast **a runner** as one can be whose legs differ greatly in length.
>
> They are as fast **a track team** as you will find, where each of its members has legs that differ greatly in length.

As an alternative you can use **each** with a plural noun in a prepositional phrase:

> **Each of these cars** is as good **a car** as you can hope to find in your price range.
>
> **Each of these runners** is as fast **a runner** as one can be whose legs differ greatly in length.

Comment: Yes. "**a** noun" = **an example of the class of** "noun" -> As good a man as you will find = As good **an example of the class of "man"** as you will find.