# Is the phrase 'not bad an attempt' correct grammatically?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

A friend asked me the other day if the phrase 'not bad an attempt' is correct grammatically or not. It seems correct to me, but a bit strange at the same time. Could someone shed some light on this?

This is my first time asking a question here, so please bear with me.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not gonna argue with the linguistic competence of [*Still, this is **not bad an effort** at all and would make one listen with care despite its several semi-sleepy qualities.*](http://www.thethrashmetalguide.com/AN-AR.html) In fact, I'd say that even just the use of the word "several" there suggests a careful / competent writer.

Comment: ...here's another one: [***Not bad a price** considering the rarity of them and the fact that Adidas and Nike seem to be pricing their trainers for close to £100 these days.*](https://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?h=0&f=210&t=1186576&i=5840) Unusual phrasing, but certainly not *unknown*. And I quite like it.

Comment: "Not a bad attempt" would be better than "not bad an attempt" in FF's first example.  Likewise "not a bad price" would be better in FF's second.

Comment: Yeah, I know they would've better. But I'm more curious about the grammatical accuracy of these phrases, is all. Looks like they are grammatically accurate phrases, just not canonical

Comment: I'd say [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+bad+an+attempt%2Cnot+a+bad+attempt%2Cnot+bad+a+try%2Cnot+a+bad+try&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20a%20bad%20attempt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20a%20bad%20try%3B%2Cc0) strongly indicate that 'not bad a/n' is non-standard. Contrast 'not too bad an attempt'.

Comment: @lbf: You (and any other users) are welcome to use *anything* from my comments in your own answers. I don't *ask* for attribution, but I won't object if you include it.

Answer (score 2):

**Not bad an attempt* is in fact not a grammatical noun phrase.

English noun phrases can have both articles and adjectives, but the articles have to come before the adjectives. *An* is an article and *bad* is an adjective. So the order has to be changed.

- *Not a bad attempt* is a grammatical noun phrase.

*Not bad* is grammatical by itself, but only when it's a predicate adjective that follows an auxiliary verb, like

- *This attempt is not bad.*

The *not* is part of the verb phrase *is not bad* here.

But in the ungrammatical **not bad an attempt*, *not bad* doesn't form a constituent because it's not part of a verb phrase, and so there's no reason to move the adjective *bad* in front of the article *an*.

Comment: “the articles have to come before the adjectives”—What about the “big mess” construction (“[not that good a review](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343861/if-i-can-say-not-that-good-a-review-does-that-mean-i-can-say-not-that-good-r)”)?

Comment: It's a big mess, all right. That's a special construction; _not that good a review_ is short for _not a review as good as that_; equatives and comparatives always have weird grammar.

Comment: In both of @FumbleFingers examples, the *an effort/a price* provides a reference for the dummy subject (which is elided in the second). As in the big mess example, rewording yields 'Still, this effort is not bad at all and would make one listen with care despite its several semi-sleepy qualities.' The adjective ahead of the determiner doesn't directly modify the following NP. Instead, it operates on the dummy subject, which transfers to the noun phrase. And the results aren't always the same. The owner is short/The owner is short a cook/The owner is a short cook.

Answer (score 2):

Devil's Advocate:

the ungrammatical **not bad an X**

paraphrasing @FumbleFingers:

> I'm not going to argue with the linguistic competence of:
>
> [Still, this is not bad an effort at all and would make one listen
>   with care despite its several semi-sleepy qualities.](http://www.thethrashmetalguide.com/AN-AR.html)
>
> and
>
> [Not bad a price considering the rarity of them and the fact that
>   Adidas and Nike seem to be pricing their trainers for close to £100
>   these days.](https://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?h=0&f=210&t=1186576&i=5840)
>
> Unusual phrasing, but certainly not unknown. And I quite like it.

I like it too ... not grammatical but used often, especially spoken.  I do also acknowlege @WS2 :'it better slides off the tongue in constructions involving *not too bad a(n) X*'.

Google books is littered with **not bad an**.

> He had [not bad an](https://books.google.com/books?id=A-oLAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22not%20bad%20an%22&pg=PA653#v=onepage&q=%22not%20bad%20an%22&f=false) opportunity of bringing the Bill in earlier.

So i say use it, knowing its un′gram·mat′i·cal′i·ty ... to add 'flavor' to the written and spoken English lexicon. I hope this is ... **not bad an answer**!

Comment: You've clarified my own feelings, so I can hardly deny you the upvote! But you might consider including a nod to [@WS2's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446667/is-the-phrase-not-bad-an-attempt-correct-grammatically?noredirect=1#comment1073897_446677) pointing out how much more easily it "slides off the tongue" in constructions involving *not **too** bad a [try, time, whatever]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - nod done.

Answer (score 0):

@junkquill "canonical" would not be the appropriate word. Part of standard written or spoken English would be the correct descriptor. The litmus test here is both what is in common parlance and what is sufficiently clear to be understood. "Not bad an attempt" is not colloquially or grammatically correct. When an adjective modifies a noun, the article is not typically placed between the adjective and the noun. The article will modify the adjective and noun together in agreement.

not bad an attempt also sounds in spoken English like a non-native construction, or only an afterthought at putting the idea together. In my opinion.

Comment: I tend to agree. This form comes into its own if you want to say "...not too bad an attempt", where "...not a too bad attempt" would be awkward and unidiomatic.

Comment: Not too bad an answer, but not comprehensive, and lacking supporting evidence.

Comment: agree ... not bad an answer!

Comment: @WS2: I *knew* there was some closely-related variant that wasn't ridiculously uncommon, but I just couldn't think of it yesterday. Google Books claims 669 hits for [*had not **too** bad a*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22had+not+too+bad+a%22), and a quick glance suggests most of them are for the specific construction being examined here. And I would just add that I have no sense whatsoever of this being something a non-native speaker might come up with. It seems to me something *only* a native speaker would ever be likely to use (rightly or wrongly by others' lights! :)

Comment: ...and never mind 669 hits for that one. Google Books claims over 3000 hits for [*not too bad **of** a (noun).*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22not+too+bad+of+a%22) Including that extra ***too*** makes all the diffference.